# Form url not showing properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have this URL for my edit form :

```
<%=form_for @cad,:url =>{:action => "update",:controller => "cad" } do |f| %>
```

And it should point to `"/cad/update"`,but the URL is pointing to "cad/6".

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is in your routes.rb file for cad?  /cad/6 is generally the correct route for an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's perfectly fine if you follow restful routes for update it's a member route
There are 2 types of route

first one is `collection route` which will work on in general for all object like `index` action and second one is `member route` which will work on `specific object` like `show,edit,update,destroy` etc ,

In your case update is member route it has http verbs is `put` and it's basically `post` request
you can check http method 
  and You don't need url hash on form rails pick it routes based on object

Comment: So ... how can I point this to "/cad/update" as my function name is update.

Comment: why you want this it's form action no one knows unless and untill error occurs

Comment: I have a  function named 'update' on my cad controller which will update the data but it won't got to update function as it is pointing to "cad/6" it won't go in update function it is giving me no routes defined error.

Comment: what is your route file contains

Comment: resources :cad then it will wor, just remove url params it's not necessary

Comment: instead of post try put and check or add :on => :member

Comment: Aaah it works now, I restarted my server and removed URL, idk what was the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: grate solved the issue just understand routes you can refer more http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3